# Showing pending friend requests

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I would like to have a table display a list of pending friend requests. THe way in which I am tracking the status of friend requests is by using Parse as a backend and creating a FriendRequest class. In that class there is a status column which has accepted, pending, denied. Here is the currently query logic.

```
 PFQuery *userQuary = [PFUser query];
    PFQuery *pendingFriends = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FriendRequest"];
    PFQuery *aceeptedFriends = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FriendRequest"];
    [aceeptedFriends whereKey:@"toUser" equalTo:self.currentUser.objectId];
    [aceeptedFriends whereKey:@"status" equalTo:@"Accepted"];
    [pendingFriends whereKey:@"status" doesNotMatchKey:@"status" inQuery:aceeptedFriends];
    [pendingFriends whereKey:@"toUser" equalTo:self.currentUser.objectId];
    [pendingFriends whereKey:@"status" equalTo:@"Pending"];
    [userQuary whereKey:@"objectId" matchesKey:@"fromUser" inQuery:pendingFriends];
    [userQuary findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error){
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }else{
            self.friendList = objects;
            NSLog(@"%@", self.friendList);
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }];
```

The problem that I am encountering is that friends who are already accepted keep showing up within the query for pending friends.

Here is the method that acts as the accepting the friend request. 
    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {

```
    PFRelation *myRelation = [self.currentUser relationForKey:@"friendRelation"];
    //PFRelation *friendsRelation = [self.selectedUser relationForKey:@"friendRelation"];
    PFObject *friendRequest = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"FriendRequest" ];
    [friendRequest setObject:self.currentUser.objectId forKey:@"fromUser"];
    [friendRequest setObject:self.selectedUser.objectId forKey:@"toUser"];
    [friendRequest setObject:@"Accepted" forKey:@"status"];

    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
            [friendRequest saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (error){
                    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

                }
            }];
            [myRelation addObject:self.selectedUser];
            [self.currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (error){
                    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);

                }
            }];

        case 2:
            [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:0];
            break;
    }
    /*
    [self.currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (error){
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
     */
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the pending friend requests you should do something like this:

```
PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];
PFQuery *pendingFriends = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FriendRequest"];

// Supposing the user at which ask the friend request
[pendingFriends whereKey:@"toUser" equalTo:self.currentUser.objectId];

// Only pending state flag
[pendingFriends whereKey:@"status" equalTo:@"Pending"];

// get all users that have asked a friend request to current user
[userQuery whereKey:@"objectId" matchesKey:@"fromUser" inQuery:pendingFriends];

// run the inner query
[userQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error){
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }else{
        self.pendingUserRequests = objects;            
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}];


...
..
.

-(void) acceptUserRequestAtIndex:(NSUInteger)pendingUserIndex
{
    // This is the currently existing user that want friendship
    // Note that my tableview datasource is the same of code above, so the previously loaded list of pending friend request users
    PFUser* selectedPendingUser = [self.pendingUserRequest objectAtIndex:pendingUserIndex];

    // Composing the query for obtain CURRENT EXISTING friend request between current user and applicant pending user
    PFQuery *friendRequestQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FriendRequest"];
    [friendRequestQuery whereKey:@"toUser" equalTo:self.currentUser.objectId];
    [friendRequestQuery whereKey:@"fromUser" equalTo:selectedPendingUser.objectId];     
    [friendRequestQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error){
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }else{

            if ([objects count] == 0){
                NSLog(@"You can't accept a non existing friend request!");
                return;
            } 

            // IMPORTANT: I'm assuming that you could find ONLY one request with the same toUser and fromUser combination!! So in your function in which you make a new request, you should check that another request with same toUser and fromUser already exist, and so avoid to make new one
            PFObject* requestRowObj = [objects objectAtIndex:0]; 
            [requestRowObj setObject:@"Accepted" ForKey:@"status"]; // change the status request between current user and applicant pending user to Accepted

            // Update the existing object on server with new modification ( so the only status field )
            [requestRowObj  saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)   {
                if (error){
                    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                }
            }];
    }];
}
```

In this way, you will avoid to select again the now accepted friend requests, since they have been flagged as accepted. Keep in mind that if you call saveInBackgroundWithBlock method of PFObject ( PFUser is a subclass of PFObject too) you will perform an UPDATE if the object has been selected from a previous query action, and will perform an INSERT if you make a new PFObject (eg :`PFObject *friendRequest = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"FriendRequest"` ];
    )

(Note: don't forget to paginate this query with skip and limit properties, according with parse selection limitation, if you think you could have over 1000 results for this query)

Hope it helps

Comment: THe problem that I am experiencing is that if the user accepts the friend request, the status is set to Accepted. However, the old status of Pending still remains within a separate row and I don't want to constantly see old pending requests that are no longer valid in my app.

Comment: Once you accept the request you know the Object id of user that has just been accepted, and you know the current user object id, so simply going into the class FriendRequest and Select that specific row with that "toUser" and that "fromUser" and update his status field to accepted. So Save in background with PFObject method saveInBackgroundWithBlock . In this way from next time that user request won't appear anymore in your pending requests

Comment: Could you go into more detail on that bit? Simply setting fromUser and toUser with the same keys isn't going to cause a replacement, its going to create a new row within the FriendRequest table. I have also updated my code above to include the method which is changing the status, but currently its creating a new row within the table rather than updating it.

Comment: As i can read above, you are make a new PFObject and then saving in background. This will create a new row server side. You should instead query the FriendRequest table and retrieve the current existing row that have the fromUser and toUser with proper values. I'll update mi code to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to updating the status within the same row.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    self.selectedUser = [self.friendList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ wants to add you as a connection", self.selectedUser.username];
    UIAlertView *confirmationAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Pending Connection Request"  message:requestString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil  otherButtonTitles:@"Accept", @"Cancel", nil];
    [confirmationAlert show];

}
```

We have set self.selectedUser as a property and it can now be used as a datasource to pass the information that we need into another method.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    PFQuery *rowIdQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FriendRequest"];
    [rowIdQuery whereKey:@"toUser" equalTo:self.currentUser.objectId];
    [rowIdQuery whereKey:@"fromUser" equalTo:self.selectedUser.objectId];
    [rowIdQuery whereKeyExists:@"objectId"];


    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
            [rowIdQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
                if(error){
                    NSLog(@" ERROR: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                }else{
                    [object setObject:@"Accepted" forKey:@"status"];
                    [object saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                        if (error){
                            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                        }else{
                            NSLog(@"Save Happoned");
                        }
                    }];
                }
            }];


           case 2:
            [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:0];
            break;
}
```

Queries can fetch objects, and those objects can have setKey forKey methods set on them. This is the preferred method according to the Parse API.